# TaskStackBuilder transition animation

Tags: android, animation, android-intent, taskstackbuilder

I'm using Android L transitions passing an `ActivityOptions` bundle in intent.
How can I reproduce the animation on the same intent with `TaskStackBuilder`?

This is my current working method with a single `Intent`:

```
startActivity(myIntent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
```

This is my try with `TaskStackBuilder`:

```
 TaskStackBuilder builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
 builder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(myIntent);
 builder.startActivities(ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
```

But the animation creates a strange effect, not the same one of the "single-intent" version.

I also tried with:

```
builder.addNextIntent(myIntent);
```

instead of:

```
builder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(myIntent);
```

Comment: Did you declare a parent activity in the manifest when your using `.addNextIntentWithParentStack()`?

Comment: @Mibit no, and I can't do it because the activity is in a separate library

Answer (score 1):

After digging inside `TaskStackBuilder`'s implementation, the problem is that it forces adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` to the 1st intent in the stack, which makes that strange effect, so use the following to start the stack:

```java
Intent[] intents = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                     .addNextIntentWithParentStack(myIntent)
                     .getIntents();
if (intents.length > 0) {
    intents[0].setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);// Or any other flags you want, but not the `.._CLEAR_..` one
}
// `this` inside current activity, or you can use App's context
this.startActivities(intents, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
```

The idea here is to still use the `TaskStackBuilder` for creating your intents' stack, then remove the weird `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` that the `TaskStackBuilder` adds to the 1st intent, then start the activities manually using any Context you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it using:

```
TaskStackBuilder.create (Context context)
```

Return a new TaskStackBuilder for launching a fresh taskstack consisting of a series of activities.
Parameters -

`Context context`: The context that will launch the new task stack or generate a `PendingIntent`.

Returns,    `TaskStackBuilder` - a new TaskStackBuilder.